# Message: Undefined variable: chart

Tags: php, codeigniter, codeigniter-3

I really need help . i don't know to solve Undefined variable: chart

**ERROR**

> A PHP Error was encountered
>
> Severity: Notice
>
> Message: Undefined variable: chart
>
> Filename: shop/header.php
>
> Line Number: 242

**My Controller**

```
function mychart($id_user)
{
    $where = array('id_user' => $this->session->userdata('id_user'));
    $datachart['chart'] = $this->m_product->tampil_chart($where,'chart')->result();
    $this->load->view('shop/header',$datachart);
}
```

**My Model**

```
function tampil_chart($where,$table)
{
    $datachart =  $this->db->get_where($table,$where);
    return $datachart->result();
}
```

**View(shop/header)**

```
<div class="header-cart-content flex-w js-pscroll">
            <?php foreach($chart as $a){
      ?>
            <ul class="header-cart-wrapitem w-full">
                <li class="header-cart-item flex-w flex-t m-b-12">
                    <div class="header-cart-item-img">
                        <img src="<?php echo base_url() ?>assets/user/images/item-cart-01.jpg" alt="IMG">
                    </div>

                    <div class="header-cart-item-txt p-t-8">
                        <a href="#" class="header-cart-item-name m-b-18 hov-cl1 trans-04">
                            <?php echo $a->id_product ?>
                        </a>

                        <span class="header-cart-item-info">
                            <?php echo $a->jumlah ?>
                        </span>
                    </div>
                </li>

            </ul>  <?php } ?>
```

Comment: Can you tell us which line is 242?

Comment: 242 is <?php
       foreach($chart as $a){
       ?>

Comment: Possible duplicate of [PHP: "Notice: Undefined variable", "Notice: Undefined index", and "Notice: Undefined offset"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4261133/php-notice-undefined-variable-notice-undefined-index-and-notice-undef)

Comment: and what url u r accessing

Comment: You need to `include` your model and controller files in the view file.

Comment: what method in controller u r accessing

Comment: i want access chart in my all header

Comment: what method in controller u r accessing, if is chart then you should also include $data['chart']

Comment: i use `mychart` method

Answer (score 0, accepted):

*Remove `->result()` from `mychart` controller because you already have in model `tampil_chart` ;*

**Replace it :**

```
$datachart['chart'] = $this->m_product->tampil_chart($where,'chart')->result();
```

*with :*

```
$datachart['chart'] = $this->m_product->tampil_chart($where,'chart');
```

Your controller should be like this :

```
function mychart($id_user)
{
    $where = array('id_user' => $this->session->userdata('id_user'));
    $datachart['chart'] = $this->m_product->tampil_chart($where,'chart');
    $this->load->view('shop/header',$datachart);
}
```

Comment: remove `->result()` from `$this->m_product->tampil_chart($where,'chart')->result();` from the controller since u already have in model method `tampil_chart`

Comment: my pleasure happy coding,

Answer (score 0):

You must check the "chart" variable is defined at the view file before to iterate it.

For this example you must do it 241 line of shop/header.php:

```
<div class="header-cart-content flex-w js-pscroll">
            <?php 
            if (isset($chart)):
            foreach($chart as $a){?>
            <ul class="header-cart-wrapitem w-full">
                <li class="header-cart-item flex-w flex-t m-b-12">
                    <div class="header-cart-item-img">
                        <img src="<?php echo base_url() ?>assets/user/images/item-cart-01.jpg" alt="IMG">
                    </div>

                    <div class="header-cart-item-txt p-t-8">
                        <a href="#" class="header-cart-item-name m-b-18 hov-cl1 trans-04">
                            <?php echo $a->id_product ?>
                        </a>

                        <span class="header-cart-item-info">
                            <?php echo $a->jumlah ?>
                        </span>
                    </div>
                </li>

            </ul>  <?php } endif; ?>
```